# What's the Difference between ETH 2.0 and NEAR?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, nearprotocol, near

Etherium 2.0 and NEAR seem to be very similar in a lot of ways. Can someone detail out what the difference between the two?

Answer (score 5):

From what I can tell there are a lot of similarities between ETH 2.0 and NEAR

Designed for scalability using a sharded network
Using a proof of stake consensus algorithm to reduce power consumption and time to mine new blocks
to name a few

I think the primary difference we have is the developer and the end user experience.

Smart contracts on NEAR are written in Rust and AssemblyScript. Rust being the more robust and heavily supported an maintain language and AssemblyScript for it's ease of entry into the blockchain space for new developers, primarily those who have experience in a similar language like JS

Our named account system as another plus for NEAR users making it easy to organize and manage smart contracts with sub accounts and giving end users a easier to read account name to make the barrier of entry lower